# setTimeout delayed in firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox

I have been trying to create a setTimeout loop in my javascript application, and it works great in all browsers, except firefox. (i know, old news)
The setTimeout call is delayed for a large amount of time, maybe about 20 seconds, for some reason, when the delay is set to 500ms, 1000ms or anything like that. Ive tried some different things, but everything seems to be delayed in FF. The two null parameters needs to be set, as they in some situations may need to be called with some other values, also with a setTimeout call.

I have tried:

```
timerMessagesRequest = setTimeout(function () { 
     getSetOfSenders(null, null); 
}, pollingDelay);



timerMessagesRequest = setTimeout(function () { 
         getSetOfSenders(null, null); 
    }, pollingDelay, undefined);


timerMessagesRequest = setTimeout( 
         getSetOfSenders(null, null) 
    , pollingDelay);
```

Comment: why don't you use setInterval instead of a loop of setTimeout?

Comment: Is setInterval more compatible with FF?

Comment: I agree with @suish. `setInterval` should be the function in use here. Please try it out.

Comment: I'm crystal sure the logic how to run the loop is causing the issue.I don't see any problem with the code you put.ofc You can fix the loop logic though changing it into setInterval is easier and simpler.

Comment: Jep, i get what you are going with, and im gonna try it out. I just took over a project from some other developer, and the code is very messy. There is a bunch of logic around the setTimeout call, so it will take so time to change it.

Comment: @suish any idea why it's working in all browsers, except FF though?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up trying out with a higher polling delay (5000ms), and that worked great in FF. It just seems like 500ms was to fast for the ajax request to process before the next call, in FF.

Answer (score 1):

the code below is a sample of loop of setTimeout.

```
var foo = function(){
  setTimeout(function(){
    console.log("test");
    foo();
  },1000);
};
foo();
```

I don't see any problem runnning this on FF.
So this means the code you put ain't causing the issue.
like I said in the comment,in this case, using `setInterval` is better and harder to get a bug.
If you need more help,show us more codes

**EDITED :**
http://www-cs-students.stanford.edu/~eparker/files/other/test_settimeout.html

this could be related the reason why the issue is happening only on FF.
I see the short amount of lag when i run the page with FF which doesn't happen in chrome.

Comment: `setInterval` isn't always the best way to do timed loops. Eg. if you have possibly long running ajax calls it may happen that the next call is triggered before the last one is finished.

Comment: I am actually calling it inside an ajax call, which then repeatedly calls itself. I cant get setInterval to work. Might be because of that

Comment: did you ensure that setTimeout causes the issue?I'm wondering if it's only because it's taking long time to get ajax response.

Comment: Well, i'm assuming that its not the ajax call, since it's a very lightweight call to my database. Plus if it works just fine in all other browsers, it can't really be the ajax call that is taking 20+ times longer in FF?

Comment: I just tried making a simple example with setTimeout, and it works fine in FF. Im gonna dig into the sorrounding logic and find out why it's so delayed.